# Better way to test sign change?

Tags: objective-c, math

When looping through a sequence of numbers (eg. 0.1, -0.5, 1.0, -0.33, ...) I want a way to test whether the current number has a different sign than the previous. My code is below but -- there has got to be a better way..

```
-(bool)signChanged:(float)prev :(float)value{

    // our value is negative
    if(value < 0.0){

        // previous value is positive or zero
        if(prev >= 0.0) return true;

    // our value is positive
    }else{

        if(prev < 0.0) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: if ((value * prev) < 0) ?  (depends on what behaviour you want from 0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a such fast verification, use a macro instead of a method:

```
#define SAME_SIGN(v1,v2) (v1>=0)==(v2>=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiply your value by previous value. If the result is positive, sign hasn't changed. Otherwise, it has.

Comment: In case of overflow? Besides multiplying is more expensive.

Comment: And can't verify that if one value is zero, tough it's a smart idea.